# Объединить регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Составил регулярное выражение

```
[Гг]енеральный.[Дд]иректор.+|^[Дд]иректор[\s\S].+|Директор .+([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)? [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)? [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)?)
```

Оно собирает ФИО директора в документе.

Пример:

```
Генеральный директор    

Васил Василий Васильевич

Директор Васил Василий Васильевич
```

---

Оно выбирает полностью все, а мне надо только ФИО. Помогите решить.
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4KtMkt/1)

```
Например: ООО «Магазин «Радуга»
```

Адрес: 99999 г. Москва Тверской области ул. Октября д 13 а.
ИНН 99939999996
КПП 6999999
ОГРН 999999999999
Расчетный счет 999999999999999
Московское Отделение № 9999 ООО Сбербанк г. Москва
БИК 99999999
Корсчет 9999999999999
КОДЫ : ОООО 99999999
ОКОНХ 99999
т/факс 8(99999) 9-99-99
директор на основании устава: Валис Василий Васильевич
зам. Директора Андре Андрей Андреевич
глав. бух. : Вад Вадим Вадимович
эл.адрес авыпп2045@yandex.ru

Comment: Приведи пример текстов, дабы понять с какими данными имеем дело.

Comment: По ссылке оставил вроде, а так: "директор на основании устава: Валис Василий Васильевич","Генеральный Директор: Валис Василий Васильевич","Директор11000219311 Валис Василий Васильевич"

Comment: Т.е. двоеточия есть не всегда? Вместо них бывают цифры? 8-О

Comment: Да, в документе люди заполняют сами, и раскидано все, так что и цифры и пробелы и с новой строки, я регулярку сделал, что выделяет все нужное, но не могу именно в группу ФИО выбить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

?: - не составляет группу,
`(?:[Гг]енеральный.[Дд]иректор.+|^[Дд]иректор[\s\S].+|Директор .+)([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)? [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)? [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(?:-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)?)`

Comment: Это ваше рабочее решение?

Comment: Да, просто выделить не могу, через 2 дня только пишет

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> мне надо только ФИО

Предложу такой вариант. Реализация на JS.

```js
const txt = `Адрес: 99999 г. Москва Тверской области ул. Октября д 13 а. ИНН 99939999996 КПП 6999999 ОГРН 999999999999 Расчетный счет 999999999999999 Московское Отделение № 9999 ООО Сбербанк г. Москва БИК 99999999 Корсчет 9999999999999 КОДЫ : ОООО 99999999 ОКОНХ 99999 т/факс 8(99999) 9-99-99 директор на основании устава: Валис Василий Васильевич зам. Директора Андре Андрей Андреевич глав. бух. : Вад Вадим Вадимович эл.адрес авыпп2045@yandex.ru`
const re =/([А-Я][а-я]+\s?){3}/
const a = txt.match(re)[0]
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Забыл написать, в документе много имен и так, и я сортирую их именно по директору, чтобы в начале было. Но мне и так нужна только регулярное выражение.

Comment: @Trentus, повторю еще раз - приведи в своем вопросе примеры текстов, дабы было понятно с чем имеем дело.

Comment: Например: ООО «Магазин «Радуга»
Адрес: 99999 г. Москва Тверской области
ул. Октября д 13 а. 
ИНН 99939999996
КПП 6999999
ОГРН 999999999999 
Расчетный счет   999999999999999
Московское Отделение № 9999 ООО Сбербанк г. Москва
БИК  99999999
Корсчет 9999999999999
КОДЫ :  ОООО 99999999
ОКОНХ  99999 
т/факс 8(99999) 9-99-99
директор на основании устава: Валис Василий Васильевич
зам. Директора Андре Андрей Андреевич
глав. бух. :  Вад Вадим Вадимович
             эл.адрес авыпп2045@yandex.ru

Comment: @Trentus, смотри вариант...

Comment: мне надо только регулярное, мне некуда вставлять скрипт, можешь написать это тут? https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Trentus, так вот же она `/([А-Я][а-я]+\s?){3}/`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/o0xlFj/1, там срабатывает не правильно, выбирает все и только выборочно

Comment: Тогда извини... Я с тем ресурсом не знаком. :(

Comment: все равно, спасибо